# Normalize a combined rank column to 0-100

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compute a Distressed Index (DI) for each zipcode based on the methodology below which is not very detailed hence I am stuck at the normalize step.

Methodology:

> Each community’s (zipcode) score on the index is equivalent to its percentile
> rank across all seven measures combined. To calculate the index, each
> community is ranked (columns: var1_rank - var7_rank) (Step-1) on each
> measure. Then each community’s seven rankings are averaged and
> weighted equally to create a preliminary score (column: var_avg) (Step-2), which is then
> normalized (column: norm) into a final score that ranges from approaching 0 (most
> prosperous) to 100 (most distressed) (Step-3). Communities are then sorted into
> five quintiles, or tiers, of economic well being: prosperous,
> comfortable, mid-tier, at risk, and distressed.

**UPDATE**

I actually found out that normalize step is actually creating percentiles based on the `var_avg` column.

`0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, 40-50, 50-60, 60-70, 80-90 and 90-100`

How can I do this and create a new column `norm`?

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# Create a sample df with 7 variables

# Assign 20 random numeric values to each variable
var1 = sample(1:100, 20)
var2 = sample(1:100, 20)
var3 = sample(1:100, 20)
var4 = sample(1:100, 20)
var5 = sample(1:100, 20)
var6 = sample(1:100, 20)
var7 = sample(1:100, 20)

# Create 20 sequential zipcodes 
Zipcode = seq(11111, 11130, by = 1)

# Create 20 random population values
Pop = sample(50:10000000, 20)

# Merge the objects into a df
df = data.frame(Zipcode, Pop, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7)

# Step-1
df$var1_rank = round(rescale(df$var1, to = c(1,10)), 0)
df$var2_rank = round(rescale(df$var2, to = c(1,10)), 0)
df$var3_rank = round(rescale(df$var3, to = c(1,10)), 0)
df$var4_rank = round(rescale(df$var4, to = c(1,10)), 0)
df$var5_rank = round(rescale(df$var5, to = c(1,10)), 0)
df$var6_rank = round(rescale(df$var6, to = c(1,10)), 0)
df$var7_rank = round(rescale(df$var7, to = c(1,10)), 0)

#Step-2
# Create a new column to calculate the averages from the variables combined for each zipcode 
df$var_avg = round(rowMeans(df[, 10:16]),0)

# Step-3
# Normalize the new column with respect to population
df$norm = df$var_avg/df$Pop

# df$norm does not make sense, stuck.......
```

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(Zipcode = c(11111, 11112, 11113, 11114, 11115, 
11116, 11117, 11118, 11119, 11120, 11121, 11122, 11123, 11124, 
11125, 11126, 11127, 11128, 11129, 11130), Pop = c(9994550L, 
3296411L, 400789L, 8011290L, 8117133L, 1747269L, 4480892L, 916748L, 
6508430L, 2201447L, 3815419L, 9167892L, 7543386L, 5729254L, 6454640L, 
4861636L, 3837436L, 3559397L, 4675782L, 9745784L), var1 = c(59L, 
18L, 62L, 93L, 33L, 94L, 38L, 47L, 25L, 20L, 41L, 5L, 77L, 66L, 
80L, 32L, 87L, 57L, 28L, 69L), var2 = c(4L, 50L, 25L, 48L, 75L, 
81L, 2L, 42L, 94L, 17L, 33L, 64L, 62L, 97L, 18L, 21L, 83L, 22L, 
31L, 6L), var3 = c(17L, 49L, 25L, 51L, 71L, 19L, 78L, 68L, 5L, 
21L, 72L, 30L, 87L, 6L, 46L, 23L, 55L, 27L, 39L, 50L), var4 = c(36L, 
43L, 76L, 6L, 29L, 12L, 1L, 78L, 93L, 52L, 27L, 21L, 66L, 14L, 
99L, 73L, 84L, 75L, 28L, 82L), var5 = c(83L, 92L, 47L, 16L, 26L, 
36L, 34L, 7L, 89L, 100L, 51L, 54L, 79L, 57L, 30L, 60L, 5L, 15L, 
80L, 61L), var6 = c(22L, 4L, 28L, 9L, 13L, 79L, 25L, 35L, 81L, 
7L, 23L, 74L, 60L, 32L, 51L, 40L, 43L, 88L, 100L, 50L), var7 = c(96L, 
8L, 23L, 36L, 41L, 97L, 45L, 19L, 18L, 6L, 20L, 93L, 94L, 17L, 
82L, 38L, 68L, 67L, 90L, 78L), var1_rank = c(6, 2, 7, 10, 4, 
10, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 1, 8, 7, 9, 4, 9, 6, 3, 7), var2_rank = c(1, 
6, 3, 5, 8, 8, 1, 5, 10, 2, 4, 7, 7, 10, 3, 3, 9, 3, 4, 1), var3_rank = c(2, 
6, 3, 6, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1, 3, 8, 4, 10, 1, 6, 3, 6, 3, 5, 6), var4_rank = c(4, 
5, 8, 1, 4, 2, 1, 8, 9, 6, 3, 3, 7, 2, 10, 8, 9, 8, 3, 8), var5_rank = c(8, 
9, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 9, 10, 5, 6, 8, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 8, 6), var6_rank = c(3, 
1, 3, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 8, 1, 3, 8, 6, 4, 5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 5), var7_rank = c(10, 
1, 3, 4, 4, 10, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 10, 10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 7, 9, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete Step-3, based on the updated information you provided, you can create percentiles based on the `var_avg` column. These percentiles can be created using the `ntile()` function from `dplyr`. See "[Bucket a numeric vector into n groups](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ntile.html)"

Given the Distressed Index formula:

[image: v_N = c + \left( \frac{(v_I - a)}{d_I} \times d_N \right)]

Where:

- `v_N` : is the normalized value
- `c`: is the start of the target range (0 in this case)
- `v_I`: is the individual preliminary score value (from `var_avg` column)
- `a`: is the minimum value of the preliminary score column (`var_avg`)
- `d_I`: is the difference between the maximum and minimum of the preliminary score column (`var_avg`)
- `d_N`: is the range of the normalization target (100 in this case since we want values from 0 to 100)

Your algorithm would be to:

- Find `a` (the minimum of `var_avg` column) and `b` (the maximum of `var_avg` column).
- Compute `d_I` as `b - a`.
- `d_N` is 100 since our target range is [0,100].
- `c` is 0.
- For each value `v_I` in `var_avg`, apply the formula to compute K.

```r
# Step-3: Normalize using the formula
# Compute minimum and maximum of var_avg
a <- min(df$var_avg)
b <- max(df$var_avg)

# Desired normalization range
c <- 0
d <- 100

# Applying the normalization formula for every row
df$norm = c + ((df$var_avg - a) / (b - a) * (d - c))

# Convert normalized values to percentiles
df$norm_percentile = ntile(df$norm, 10) * 10

# Print the resultant dataframe
print(df[, c("Zipcode", "var_avg", "norm", "norm_percentile")])
```

That would give you the `norm` column in your dataframe that represents the desired normalized value for each zip code based on percentiles.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the formula and providing serep by step information. This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: On a side, note can you please tell me if I did the ranking correctly in `Step-2`? Like I know there's also a [RANK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723) function in `MS-Excel` that ranks the values. so is the `RANK` function method more appropriate or the `rescale` function I used in my code? Or both methods are fine?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy If the objective is to determine the relative positioning of the zip codes based on their average values, then a ranking function like Excel's RANK (or R's rank function) would be appropriate.

If the goal is to transform the data to fit into a certain range (like 0 to 100, which is your case), then the rescale function is suitable. So Step 2 is OK.

Answer (score 2):

"Normalizing" means that a range [a,b] will be mapped into other [c,d] range.

First we need maximum distances

```
dI = b - a
dN = d - c
```

And now any value `vI` in [a,b] range can be normalized by

```
vN = c + ( (vI - a) / dI * dN )
```

---

In your case, the initial range [a,b] is possible (or avalilable) values of  the column created for "preliminary score". And the normalized range is [0, 100]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I actually found some additional information, please see question update, thank you.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy No. Getting a normalized value is not assigning it to a "slot" (such as 30-40 interval)

Comment: Thank you, if it's not much to ask then, can you please explain it further with the `sample data` ? Like I am confused what goes into `b`, `a`, `d`, `c` `vI`?

Comment: I have added some sample data for further convience. Can you please explain it a it further for like zipcode `11111`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a linear mapping from one closed interval `[u1, u2]` to a new closed interval `[v1, v2]`, you can apply a linear algebra operation like below

```
v1 = a*u1 + b
v2 = a*u2 + b
```

and the solution `[a; b]` can be written as

```
[a; b] = [[u1,1]; [u2,1]]^(-1) * [v1; v2]
```

where `^(-1)` and `*` denote matrix inverse and matrix product, respectively. Then, the solved tuple `(a, b)` defines the linear mapping.

## One implementation

```
LinearMapping <- function(x, newRange) {
    cbind(x, 1) %*% solve(t(rbind(range(x), 1)), matrix(newRange))
}
```

## Example

```
> set.seed(0)

> (x <- runif(20, 5, 20))
 [1] 18.450458  8.982630 10.581858 13.592800 18.623117  8.025229 18.475845
 [8] 19.170129 14.911967 14.436711  5.926794  8.089619  7.648351 15.305343
[15] 10.761556 16.547621 12.465489 15.764278 19.878591 10.700528

> LinearMapping(x, c(0, 100))
 [1]  89.76380  21.90281  33.36534  54.94637  91.00134  15.04061  89.94577
 [8]  94.92207  64.40154  60.99513   0.00000  15.50212  12.33932  67.22108
[15]  34.65333  76.12515  46.86632  70.51051 100.00000  34.21590
```